# Power Analysis for Non-sinusoidal excitations

Tags: power, ac, superposition

For a series RLC circuit excited by a non-sinusoidal voltage expressed as any Fourier sum, we calculate the absorbed power using the formula:
ΣVI \$\cos \theta\$ where \$\theta\$ represents the phase difference between voltage and current for some harmonic. 
i.e. P<sub>total</sub> = V<sub>1</sub>I<sub>1</sub> \$\cos \theta\$<sub>1</sub> + V<sub>2</sub>I<sub>2</sub> \$\cos \theta\$<sub>2</sub>

Basically we are adding the powers obtained by considering each harmonic as a separate source to get the P<sub>total</sub> for the actual source.(superposition theorem) My question is, we know that power calculations can NOT be done using Superposition Theorem as the expression for power is not LINEAR but we're still getting the right answer anyway! Can someone help me get my head around this?

Comment: Certainly power can be calculated using superposition so what's your real question?

Comment: I know you can find out the power for a multiple Source circuit by adding up the voltages and currents for each source separately and then p=vi. But can you find the power for each source separately and then add them up to get the total power dissipated? Isn't that what we're doing here?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. Why don't you post a real question rather than staying with a generic problem that clearly we don't see eye to eye on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at this is, when you integrate over time to calculate power, all cross terms with different frequencies integrate to zero, because sinusoidal of different frequencies are orthogonal.

A very simple case as example:
$$\int (v_1 \cos(w_1 t) + v_2 \cos(w_2 t))^2 dt = \int (v_1 \cos(w_1 t))^2 dt + \int (v_2 \cos(w_2 t))^2 dt$$
because
$$\int v_1 v_2 \cos(w_1 t) \cos(w_2 t) dt = 0$$

Therefore calculating the power of each frequency then adding them together is equal to adding the voltages (and currents) together then calculating the power.